# want to show save as draft content in a view drupal

Tags: drupal, view

I have one page which is 'saved as draft' (drupal status is 'not published' in the backend).

I have a view which shows only published pages.

I want to show the saved as draft content in the above view.

How can i achieve this. Problem is that saved as draft content is unpublished content and thus doesn't display in view.

Thanks!

Comment: I'm not sure, but do you want to list all nodes on a view whether it's published or not? Mybe you want only to show the drafts?

Comment: How about creating an attachment linked onto that view which has it's own filter criteria for nodes that are unpublished?

Comment: i need to show draft contents but not the unpublished once.

Answer (score 0):

When you are making a view you automatically get filter "published" to true. So, for displayin unpublished content clone that view (or make another display) and in that new copy just change that filter to display unpublished content instead of published. It's under filter options.

Comment: for clarification: i don't want all the unpublished content to get displayed, just Draft one's.